# How does my user access a ServiceNow application that I created?

Tags: servicenow

I am researching ServiceNow, I know next to nothing about it. Funny how the most obvious questions seem to be the hardest to Google. My specific question is about applications.

ServiceNow runs as SaaS, correct? So, if I build a ServiceNow application, for a user to access that application, they would open the ServiceNow platform in their browser, then they would have a menu of applications they could launch, correct?

Is it possible to host a ServiceNow application on a specific page, or on a website, or embed it in a SharePoint page, so I can give out a URL for a user to run the application? Or do they always have to navigate through the ServiceNow portal to run my application?

I know this sounds like a dumb question. But everything I have read assumes you already know this information, so a dumb, obvious question it has to be.

Answer (score 1):

ServiceNow assumes that it is managing the entire window (or tab). You might be able to get something to work using HTML frames, but there is a good chance it would break with a future ServiceNow upgrade.

On the other hand, it possible to redirect a user into a specific ServiceNow page by constructing the appropriate URL. If the user does not already have an active session cookie then ServiceNow will prompt them to authenticate. You can redirect to a specific Service Portal page, or a specific catalog item or a specific record. You can redirect to a ServiceNow Dashboard. If you want to show a list of records, you can dynamically build a query. You can redirect into Agent Workspace or the classic platform UI. If directing into the classic platform UI you can show or hide the ServiceNow navigation menu based on whether or not your URL contains `nav_to.do?`.

There is a bit of an introduction on this page, although it really only scratches the surface:

- https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/sandiego-platform-user-interface/page/use/navigation/reference/r_NavigatingByURLExamples.html

If you want to drive ServiceNow from a web site or from SharePoint, then you just need to construct the right URL which will open ServiceNow in a new browser tab.

Comment: So to be clear, any ServiceNow app is going to run from the ServiceNow portal, and I can't embed it like a Java Applet or a Power Apps application in some other site.